# CGAL: What is join_facet() really doing with circulators?

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to use `join_facet()` iteratively to grow a single facet starting from a given `facet_handle`. However, I'm running into trouble when using the `Halfedge_around_facet_circulator` in combination with `join_facet()`. My while-loop does not become false anymore which works fine if I don't use `join_facet()` and the circulator seems to point to something else.

I assume that the join operation is somehow changing that `Halfedge_around_facet_circulator`. But why and how to solve this?

```cpp
  Polyhedron P_out; // is a valid pure triangle Polyhedron
  bool merge_next = true;
  while (merge_next == true) {
    Polyhedron::Halfedge_around_facet_circulator hit = facet_handle->facet_begin(); // facet_handle pointing to facet of P_out
    merge_next = false;
    do {
      if(!(hit->is_border_edge())) {
        if (coplanar(hit->facet(), hit->opposite()->facet())) {
          if (CGAL::circulator_size(hit->opposite()->vertex_begin()) >= 3 && CGAL::circulator_size(hit->vertex_begin()) >= 3
&& hit->facet()->id() != hit->opposite()->facet()->id()) {
            Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle hit2 = hit;
            P_out->join_facet(hit2);
            merge_next = true;
          }
        }
      }
    } while (++hit != facet_handle->facet_begin());
  }
```

What this code should do:
Given the `facet_handle`, iterate over the corresponding halfedges of facet and merge if possible. Then taking `facet_handle` of created new facet again and doing the same until no neighboring facets are left to merge.

Edit:
There are areas on which the code runs fine and others where it crashes at `hit->is_border_edge()` after the first `join_facet()`.

Comment: What is iterator, and what is P_out.

Comment: Forgot to change this in the minimal example: iterator is facet_handle and P_out is a pure triangle Polyhedron. Edited it in the code.

Comment: What is the role of hit2. Try hit =  P_out->join_facet(hit); because hit and hit->opposite get deleted.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I tried to address by copying `hit` before `join_facet()`. Doing `hit = P_out->join_facet(hit)` gives me a long compiler error telling me: 
```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘CGAL::Polyhedron_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3>::Halfedge_around_facet_circulator and ‘CGAL::Polyhedron_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3>::Halfedge_handle
```